# How to refactor this code that can upload images before a template is defined?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

I have a function that works just fine when uploading images to an already existing (defined) template. However, I want to know if it's possible to refactor it in order to be able to upload an image before the template is defined (that is, when creating it).

This is the function:

```
newImageSelected: function (imageList) {
  let vc = this
  console.log('vc.template.id', vc.template.id)
  Template.uploadImage(vc.template, imageList[0])
    .then(function (response) {
      alert("La media ha sido cargada")
      console.log("La media ha sido cargada", response.data)
      if (!vc.template.images) vc.template.images = []
      vc.template.images.push(response.data)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      alert("Hubo un error cargando la media")
    })
}
```

And this is `uploadImage`:

```
function uploadImage (template, image) {

  let formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('image', image)
  console.log("uploadImage - template.id: " + template.id)

  return axios.post(API.templateUploadImage(template.id), formData)
}
```

Logging `template.id`writes `undefined`. I tried assigning a temporary template.id equal to the length of the array but that doesn't work because axios tries to push to a non existing URL.

Comment: How are "already defined" templates getting their id in the first place? Are you randomly generating them and sending them to the server when you call the save, or are they assigned on the server and returned to you? Did you write the API, or was it provided for you? Looks like this is more an API issue than a javascript one, whoever is providing your api should provide standard id value to send for saving new templates (for instance, the string 'new').

Comment: What's the server API for doing what you want?